# Why it shows blank instead of picture in my Tkinter program?

Tags: python, image, macos, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to use Tkinter to display all the pictures in a specific directory, so I firstly code to show all the pictures from a given list

The code is:

```
import os

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Application(Frame):
    def add_pic_panel(self, pic):
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic))
        label = Label(root, image = img)
        print label
        return label

    def create_gui(self):
        pics = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg']
        for pic in pics:
            self.add_pic_panel(pic)
        pass

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_gui()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Environment: Mac OS 10.9, Python 2.7.5
How could I display all the pictures in the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The code does not pack the label.
2. Should keep the reference for the image.

---

```
def add_pic_panel(self, pic):
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic))
    label = Label(self.master, image=img)
    label.img = img # to keep the reference for the image.
    label.pack() # <--- pack
    return label
```

BTW, `add_pic_panel` use `root` directly. It would be better to use `self.master`.

`root.destroy()` at the last line cause `TclError` when closing the window. Remove the line.

Comment: What does "keep the reference for the image" mean?(I'm a Chinese, and I don't get this sentence. And why still need to pack after initialized the label with img?

Comment: @kxxoling, Remove the `label.img = img` and run the program. You will see no image.

Comment: @kxxoling, If you don't keep the reference  for the images object, it is garbage collected.

Comment: But I don't want to reference img twice, any other better way to realize this?

Comment: @kxxoling, Packing containing frame does not automatically pack contained widgets. Think about the case when contained widgets use different layout method: `grid`, `place` instead of `pack`.

Comment: @kxxoling, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Am I using the wrong word? I mean how to display the pictures in the given box with the word 'img' only appear once?

Comment: @kxxoling, Try `def add_pic_panel(self, pic): label = Label(self.master); label['image'] = label.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic)); label.pack(); return label`.

Comment: It's the same but looks better. Thanks!